# How to add a ads.txt

Tags: reactjs, next.js, adsense

So, I want to add a ads.js to my site, but the example from Next github is not so clear. Anyone knows how to do it? 
Here's the next example with robots and a sitemap:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sitemap-and-robots-express-server

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on where is this file needs to go you can do one of this options.

1. if not matter, just drop it inside the `/static` folder and call it whit `go.to/static/ads.txt`
2. drop it inside `/static` folder and add this script to your custom server to handle this new path `/ads.txt` in the way to make accessible with `go.to/ads.txt`

```js
server.get('/ads.txt', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = join(__dirname, 'static/ads.txt')
  app.serveStatic(req, res, filePath)
})

server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))
```

this solution work in the express server.

Answer (score 6):

Just add your ads.txt file inside the `/public` folder.

Comment: i have added there itself, and it has been 1 week, still it is showing the same error, what should i do?

Comment: This worked for me, but also needed to rebuild my project and deploy it to hosting.

Comment: But isn't that sensitive data that must be hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've setup a static directory in node & using express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Simply place the 'ads.txt' file in the 'public' directory and it will automatically be served / available via a get request to yourapp.com/ads.txt

Answer (score 0):

You must add `ads.txt` in `web.config` file on server to have authorization for your website from google ads:

Example:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/ads.txt)" negate="true" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).